# Why use export and export default with same "interface"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the reason for:

```
import something1 from './something1'
import something2 from './something2'

export default {
  something1,
  something2
}

export {
  something1,
  something2
}
```

?

And why isn't possible to do:

```
export default something
export something
```

Thank you.

Comment: are you getting errors? what are you trying to do that you cant do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For the case where you want individual module elements *and* a library namespace.  If this were the old days:

   ```
   import { extend } from "jquery";
   import $ from "jquery";
   ```

   One of these is importing a named export, and one of these is importing the default. Either is valid. But in general, the common practice is individual exports.
2. Because an export statement is either expecting you to declare the thing inline

   ```
   export const something = ...
   ```

   Which means that it can't be reassigned as `default` as well...
   Or it's expecting you to export a batch of named values.

   ```
   export default something;
   export { something };
   ```